# Argument is always null when using RemoteAttribute

Tags: model-view-controller, data-annotations

I am trying to make my first remote-validation in MVC, which I cannot get to work since the argument my validation action receives is always null.

```
public class Book
{
  [Remote("IsValidDate", "Validation")]
  public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have some other values I need outside the Book class, wherefore I also created a BookModel:

```
public class BookModel
{
  public Book Book;
  public string SomeOtherValueNotInterestingInThisExample;
  public BookModel(Book book)
  {
    Book = book;
    // other stuff
  }
}
```

Then my editing page contains:

```
...
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
.... and later
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Book.ReleaseDate)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Book.ReleaseDate)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Book.ReleaseDate)
</div>
```

My ValidationController looks like this:

```
public class ValidationController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult IsValidDate(string strDate)
    {
        bool isValid = DateHelper.IsValid(strDate);
        if (isValid)
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("(remote - not valid)", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is, that my strDate argument in IsValidDate(string strDate) is always null. Appart from that my validation works fine, and if I force it to fail, it also returns the correct errormessage to the correct field.

I cannot figure out why strDate is always null. Is it because it is in a BookModel and thereby called "Book.ReleaseDate"?

Comment: If I add: 
strDate = Request.QueryString["Book.ReleaseDate"];
in front of "bool isValid = DateHalper......"
Then I get the correct result... Is there any way I can make my controller receive the date as strDate, instead of this hack? I would like to be able to reuse this IsValidDate controller with other variables as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is a hack that works for me in this case. First I must admit that I was not aware that the argument in IsValidDate must be named the same as the field I want to validate. I know that now.

Here is the changed code:

```
public class ValidationController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult IsValidDate(string date)
    {
        if (date == null)
            date = GetQueryStringValue("date");

        bool isValid = DateHelper.IsValid(date);
        if (isValid)
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

    private string GetQueryStringValue(string key)
    {
        return (from qStr in Request.QueryString.AllKeys
                where qStr.ToLower().EndsWith(key.ToLower())
                select Request.QueryString.Get(qStr)).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Note that I have made a separate GetQueryStringValue, so other validators can use the same method.

My Book class now looks like this (only the problematic fields are mentioned here):

```
public class Book
{
  [Remote("IsValidDate", "Validation", ErrorMessage = "Release date is not valid")]
  public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }


  [Remote("IsValidDate", "Validation", ErrorMessage = "Start date is not valid")]
  public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment to the solution: Basically I start to check if the argument in IsValidDate is null or not. If it is null, I go through all QueryString keys to see if there is an argument which ends with the field name I want and then populate my argument with that value.

That led me to another solution (which ONLY works here, because I know that I do not have additional fields that ends with the same field name - or should I say - partly field name). By saying that I only want to look at the partly key name "date" (instead of "releasedate") I can have this validator check all my date-fields in the View. But as mentioned: it only works, because I do not want additional fields in my Remote validation. If I wanted to compare e.g. "StartDate" with "ReleaseDate" I would get problems :-)

I have also moved my ErrorMessage to my DataAnnotations, so I can have different errormessages on the fields.

It is not nice - but it works!